# Integrate materialize in a Angular2 project with webpack and SCSS

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli, materialize

As explain in the title I'm trying to integrate Materialize in my Angular 2 project.

The project was generated with "**AngularCli**"

and Im using "**Webpack**" and "**Scss**"

The tuto I found are all differents I don't understand how to do it for a **scss** use :

[- Materialize website tuto](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

[- Npm website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize)

My angular-cli json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "accident-chain-web-angular",
    "ejected": true
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "assets/scss/main.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "preprod": "environments/environment.preprod.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

My project with materialize files added in assets :

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to use MaterializeCSS framework.

Few things to keep in mind before going to installation

- It is not a CSS only framwork, though it has CSS  name in it. We can use its SCSS too
- It is not built for Angular
- It is a component framework too built on jquery. Though we are not supposed to use jquery ( not suggested ) in angular, still we import .

You can use ***any*** of the following methods:

- CDN
- Assets
- Include in Angular (NPM)

Each has its own advantages and disadvantages.

### CDN

Just add this to `index.html` and you are good to go .

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

 <!-- We need jquery first -->  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

### Assets

Add it as an asset in your project. This helps in not depending on internet when building and running locally.

[Download jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

[Download CSS version](http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize-v0.98.2.zip)

- Extract them
- Copy `materialize.min.css`, `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` and `materialize.min.js` in your assets folder
- add them to index.html

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/materialize.min.css" >
  <script src="./assets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/materialize.min.js"></script>
  ```

### Include in angular ( NPM)

In this method we directly include the files to our angular build. I am assuming the angular project is built with `@angular/cli` for simplicity.

Do

```
npm install materialize-css --save 
npm install jquery --save
npm install url-loader --save
```

Add the following to `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
   "styles.scss"
]

"scripts":[
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
]
```

Inside `styles.scss` , add this :

```
$roboto-font-path: "~materialize-css/dist/fonts/roboto/";
@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize";
```

---

### Integration with Angular:

The above all installation methods provide full functionality with materialize and **no need to further install anything to work in angular**. 
Take any example and just use the appropriate HTML structure inside the HTML part of angular components and you are good to go.

In some instances you might need to tinker with javascript and for that we need to use jQuery. Instead of that we can use the angular wrapper developer at [angular2-materialize](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/). I developed a full functional site using angular and materialize and never felt a need for that.

If you still believe you need it . You can install as follows :

- Install materialize with any of the above mentioned ways
- Install angular2-materialize

  ```
  npm install angular2-materilize --save
  ```

  Add in angular `app.module.ts`

  ```
  import { MaterializeModule } from "angular2-materialize";

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      //...
      MaterializeModule,
    ],
    //...
  })
  ```

Follow other examples provided in the home page of `angular2-materialize`

Comment: I worked on that and this is not so simple. My project use cli and webpack. Let's say I downloaded the SASS version of materialize from http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html because I want to be able to modify scss behaviors. Then I copy/paste it in my assets folder. But I don't want jquery locally. For animations I need angular2-materialize. This is all confusing for me, everything I try gets me diferent errors, webpack/jquerry/or materialize related...

Comment: Dude, where was it mentioned to put scss file in assets. Tell what you tried and what errors you got. Are you using cli pure or cli eject ? . I gave so many options which one you tried

Comment: Even if you dont want jquery, materialize needs it so you HAVE to import it. If you dont want to do that, use either Material design lite or angular material 2 or the best 'MDC for Web'

Comment: Then where should I put the files of materialize-SASS version from the link I provided (which contains sass/js/fonts files)? This is what I need. So I guess it is corresponding with the Asset part of your answer. Every tuto I watch gives different answers.. and it is not clear what to add to my webpack config/ what to add to main.html, What to had to angula-cli. The tuto from the github of angular2materialize tells to do some of each of the methods you provided here for the integration :/ For info I did not eject the project. And for Jquery I just don't want it locally.

Comment: Because there are so many ways to do it. Choose any of the three steps mentioned above and it should work. Ignore `angular2-materialize` get it working without that.  Once we see everything is working fine , we can install that ( even though its not needed at all in reality )

Comment: The downloaded file ( from link you gave)  is same as what you get with `npm install` ( third step ) . Put the extracted contents in `src` and add to `styles` and `scripts` properties in `.angular-cli.json` as shown in step 3. The path should be something like './materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss'

Comment: That was 4th option in my answer but I found it irrelevant as npm is better than downloading the file and removed it. You can see it previous version of the post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44666551/revisions .. Take a fresh project and follow any of the solution I gave line by line, it will work . Ignore 'Integration with angular'

Comment: I think materialize-css in node_modules has a folder SASS which contains scss components. Let's say I use the NPM method for angular-css. I still need angular2materialize for using things like MaterializeAction for Modals.. So I use the Angular part of your response (I did). I get errors for fonts like : 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff'

Comment: and on npm install I get : 'angular2-materialize@15.0.4 requires a peer of materialize-css@^0.98.2 but none was installed.'

Comment: I will eat my dog food and try it myself and see what errors I get with angular2-materialize. Will update the answer if anything needs to be changed.

Comment: I too got the font error, I updated the answer to fix the font error. `npm install url-loader --save` . Moved materialize-scss loading into `styles.scss` and also declared fonts url . Ignore the npm dependency error. It should work now. If you get any error please let me know . thanks

Comment: In local it works, but the problem is when the website is build and published by jenkins : Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined  AND Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is created by the materialize-css library. Please import materialize-css before importing angular2-materialize.

Comment: You probably missed `--save` while installing 'materialize-css' . Check if it exists in your 'package.json' file.

Comment: I basically copy/paste the commands. yes it is present in the package.json

Comment: Regarding first error, it should be something related to this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/368

Comment: Fantasic answer. Wish i'd read this before the host of others i read...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Angular CLI (which I assume you meant to say that it is using Webpack and SCSS), why not move your the `scss` directory out of the `src/assets/` directory and put it into just the `src/` folder, so your location is `src/scss/`. Assets are typically non-compiled/processed resources for your apps, not the appropriate place for your SCSS.

Then you can change

```
   "styles": [
        "assets/scss/main.scss"
   ],
```

to

```
   "styles": [
        "scss/main.scss"
   ],
```

And when you run the cli (either `ng serve` or `ng build` your SCSS should be built and served with your app.

I am making the assumption that youre importing the other SCSS files in the `scss/` directory in your `main.scss`. Otherwise you can add them to the `styles` array in the `angular-cli.json`

Comment: PS You could also always import the materialize scss directly through the cli json by passing `"../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss"` into the styles array.

Comment: So doing both import the scss files into the main.scss and materialize.scss into the style array at the same time is useless ?

Comment: Are you asking if it's pointless to import both of those into the `styles` array? If the materialize.scss is already imported into the main.scss then you wouldn't need to import it again in the styles array.. (Not sure if i'm understanding you though).

Comment: Yes that's what I was asking. I'm completly new to web developpement so it may seems I'm asking dumb questions x)

Comment: Ok, then you are correct in your assessment that importing `main.scss` and `materialize.scss` both into your `styles` array is useless if `materialize` has already been imported into `main`. On a separate note, did my advice work?